# How to target outlook subfolder using powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm trying to filter about 2000 automated alerts in an outlook sub-folder.

I need to do the following series of steps:

1. Parse sub-folder `Account Alert Lockouts`
2. Search for a specific phrase that has a variable username
3. Dump out that whole phrase with the variable username into csv

Example Phrase

```
Account Name:       jdoe
```

I have all of the required emails in a sub-folder, I just need to analyze them.

I've gotten my code to work in the Inbox, but it doesn't cover the sub-folder.

```
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)    

$RE = [RegEx]'(?sm)Account Name\s*:\s*(?<AccName>.*?)$.*'

$DebugPreference = 'Continue'

$Data = foreach ($item in $inbox.items) {
    if ($item.body -match $RE) {
        Write-Host "ding "
        [PSCustomObject]@{ AccName = $Matches.AccName }
    }
}

$Data 
$Data | Export-CSv '.\data.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation for [NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder#remarks):

> To return a specific non-default folder, use the Folders collection.

And the documentation for the [Folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folders) collection referenced above:

> Use Folders (index), where index is the name or index number, to return a single Folder object. Folder names are case-sensitive.

You should be able to add this:

```bsh
$subfolder = $inbox.Folders('Account Alert Lockouts')
```

and change your `foreach` to iterate over `$subfolder`.

Comment: Ugh. I spend a couple hours researching other questions and yours is so stupid simple. I'm a big dummy.

Yeah, it worked immediately just as you said. 

Thank you.

Comment: Haha I've been there plenty of times. Glad I could help!